# gt-i7500 galaxy android samsung device usb driver

Tags: android, galaxy

unfortunately I lost cd accompanying with my cell phone model gt-i7500 galaxy android samsung

where can i get usb driver for this ? the adb is not recognising the device in windows xp

Comment: Contact device vendor? This question is suitable for http://superuser.com

Comment: This is a developers community, not software support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Samsung support site.  In the UK it's [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support).  Enter your model number and then download the most recent version of their PC Studio/PC Sync sowftware.  Installing that should also install the USB driver.

For future reference this isn't really a question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: my apology ! do you have any forum to refer ? i posted in android developer google group, it did not appear at all !

Comment: @trewn: http://android.stackexchange.com/ is probably the right site for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13667902/1352919